# How do you perform fatalities that involve the use of jumping (up arrow)?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

Say I want to make **Freddy Krueger**'s fatality, which is called **Welcome To My Nightmare**

> down, up, left, right + block

When I finish pressing the buttons, it didn't do the thing, since I'm already in the air when I press **up** and fatalities must be done on the ground.

I have no problem when the jump is right at the end of the combo, since it's the last directional button I have to press plus any "hitting/block" button.

But I always considered fatalities that involves the up button, the ones which are not at the end of the combo, as the impossible ones... unless there's a trick for them. Does someone know?

Comment: did you try after he cames down(from jump) then hit left and right ?

Comment: It wouldn't work, since combos are meant to be done fast. (I've tried that though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can avoid having your character jump during a Fatality input, but the most common method (dating back to the classic MK games) is just to perform a brief block to prevent your character from jumping. You can hold the Block button during that portion of the input, and it won't have any adverse effects. A minor complication in your case is that the Fatality in question requires the use of the Block button for the final input, but as long as you let go of the Block button before you need to press it again at the end, it should still work.

For example, to perform the Fatality you mentioned, you could do something like this:

> [Hold Block] -> Down -> Up -> [Release Block] -> Left -> Right + Block